# Instagram's geotagging API

Tags: api, location, instagram, geotagging

I'm working on learning about Instagram's API as a side project. I've followed this tutorial (http://eduvoyage.com/instagram-search-app.html) to implement a search feature by hashtag. It was extremely helpful to me. One of the things I saw in the API was the location ID feature, and I was wondering how to implement that. Through a search on this site, I found that a request can be made which will return the following.

```
'{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  {
"attribution": null,
"tags":  [],
"type": "image",
"location":  {
  "latitude": 48.8635,
  "longitude": 2.301333333
},
"comments":  {
  "count": 0,
  "data":  []
},
..........'
```

I'm trying to figure out this tutorial to process that information. (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-instagram1/index.html#retrievedetails)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</head>
<body>  
<h1>Instagram Image Detail</h1>
<?php
// load Zend classes
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

// define consumer key and secret
// available from Instagram API console
$CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID';
$CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET';

try {
  // define image id
  $image = '338314508721867526';

  // initialize client
  $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' . $image);
  $client->setParameterGet('client_id', $CLIENT_ID);

  // get image metadata
  $response = $client->request();
  $result = json_decode($response->getBody());

  // display image data
 ?>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="info">
      <h2>Meta</h2>  
      <strong>Date: </strong> 
      <?php echo date('d M Y h:i:s', $result->data->created_time); ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Creator: </strong>
      <?php echo $result->data->user->username; ?>
      (<?php echo !empty($result->data->user->full_name) ? 
        $result->data->user->full_name : 'Not specified'; ?>)
      <br/>
      <strong>Location: </strong>
      <?php echo !is_null($result->data->location) ?
      $result->data->location->latitude . ',' . 
        $result->data->location->longitude : 'Not specified'; ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Filter: </strong>
      <?php echo $result->data->filter; ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Comments: </strong>
      <?php echo $result->data->comments->count; ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Likes: </strong>
      <?php echo $result->data->likes->count; ?>
      <br/>
      <strong>Resolution: </strong>
      <a href="<?php echo $result->data->images
        ->standard_resolution->url; ?>">Standard</a> | 
      <a href="<?php echo $result->data->images
        ->thumbnail->url; ?>">Thumbnail</a>
      <br/>
      <strong>Tags: </strong>
      <?php echo implode(',', $result->data->tags); ?>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <h2>Image</h2>  
      <img src="<?php echo $result->data->images
        ->low_resolution->url; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="comments">
      <?php if ($result->data->comments->count > 0): ?>
      <h2>Comments</h2>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($result->data->comments->data as $c): ?>
          <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $c
            ->from->profile_picture; ?>" class="profile" />
          <?php echo $c->text; ?> <br/>
          By <em> <?php echo $c->from->username; ?></em> 
          on <?php echo date('d M Y h:i:s', $c->created_time); ?>
          </div>

          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>      
  </div>
<?php
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . print_r($client);
  exit;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem (I think) that I'm having is here:
    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

I downloaded Zend Frame 1.12.13, but I'm not sure what these line of code is asking for. In the Zend Framework folder, It goes "Zend/Loader(Folder)", but nothing called "Loader.php". Does that just load everything in the 'Loader' folder? Same for the Zend_Loader, there is a directory of Zend/Http/Client, but Client is also a folder.

tl;dr
Trying to set up a program that will search instagram (as linked in the tutorial above), be able to click on the picture results, open one tab that shows the picture and the users profile, and another tab that shows all the image metadata. Is there a simpler way to do this? Or a more noob friendly tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when using this example. You must include the path of the Zend framework at the very top of this example. I did it in just its own php block at the top.

```
ini_set('include_path', 'path/to/ZendFramework/library');
```